# How to fix too many in _connectionQueue of Pool?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

My very simple Node.js code doesn't seem like its connection pool work as it's supposed to do. `_connectionQueue` of `Pool` object just gets longer and longer infinitely, and app dies. I mean it does make a pool and there are pre-made connections already, but they are not reusable or insert requests are too many and fast? I'm not sure..

I've tried to put some more `connectionLimit` like following :

```
let state = { pool: null }
export const connect = () => {
  state.pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 200,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || 'password',
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'database'
  })
}

export const get = () => state.pool
```

Mostly given job of this server is subscription and insertion. It subscribes several MQTT topics and just tries to insert messages into RDB. About 100 messages arrives every second, and that code looks like this.

```
mqttClient.on('message', function (topic, message) {

    if(topic.includes('sensor')){     

      try { 
        const data = JSON.parse(message.toString())

        if(validate(data.uuid)){
          const params = [data.a, data.b, data.c, ...]
          sensor.setStatus(params)
        }
      } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
      }

    }
}
```

```
export const setStatus = (params) => {

  const SQL = `INSERT INTO ...`

  db.get().query(SQL, params, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  })
}
```

Then, I see this through `chrome-devtools`

```
Object
pool: Pool
config: PoolConfig {acquireTimeout: 10000, connectionConfig: ConnectionConfig, waitForConnections: true, connectionLimit: 200, queueLimit: 0}
domain: null
_acquiringConnections: []
_allConnections: (200) [PoolConnection, PoolConnection, …]
_closed: false
_connectionQueue: (11561) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, …]
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 0
_freeConnections: []
_maxListeners: undefined
__proto__: EventEmitter
__proto__: Object
```

---

I've put `console.log` into `setStatus` like following :

```
export const setStatus = (params) => {

  const SQL = `INSERT INTO ...`
  console.log(`allConnections=${db.get()._allConnections.length}, connectionQueue=${db.get()._connectionQueue.length}`)

  db.get().query(SQL, params, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  })
}
```

, and got these.

```
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=29
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=30
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=31
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=32
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=33
allConnections=200, connectionQueue=34
...
```

It seems like server created a connection pool very well, but not using those connections. Instead, trying to create a new connection more and more all the time and those requests just get stuck in `_connectionQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are creating a new pool every time you'd like to make a query. The common model is to create a pool once when the application starts, then use connections from that pool as needed (one pool, many connections).

Also if you're using a simple DB model you can simplify access to the pool by making it global. Below is an alternate to your code you might try:

**app.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database'
});

global.db = connection;
```

**modules.js**

```
export const setStatus = (params) => {
  let SQL = `INSERT INTO ...`
  db.query(SQL, params, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    console.log(result)
  })
}
```

Documentation for further reference :: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

**Edit 1 - Log pool events**

```
db.on('acquire', function (connection) {
  console.log('Connection %d acquired', connection.threadId);
});

db.on('connection', function (connection) {
  console.log('Pool id %d connected', connection.threadId);
});

db.on('enqueue', function () {
  console.log('Waiting for available connection slot');
});

db.on('release', function (connection) {
  console.log('Connection %d released', connection.threadId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, both my code and your recommended code get the same result. I checked like `console.log(\`allConnections=${db.get()._allConnections.length}, connectionQueue=${db.get()._connectionQueue.length}\`)` and both make connection pool but it seems like not using it? just creating a new connection request instead of using pool connection?

Comment: Can you add logging for the 4 available pool events? (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-events) I have updated my response with examples of each to try.